# BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync JPEG is 77KB resulting Bitmap is 1.6MB

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, jpeg

I'm downloading some regular JPEG files and I have verified the file size. They are 77KB and can be viewed in my browser.

`ImageBytes.Length` verifies this file size. However, `imageBitmap.byteCount` is 1638400 bytes. What am I missing? `BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync` creates usable files, but they are huge.

```
public async static Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    byte[] ImageBytes = null;

    var HttpResponseMessage = await AppController.Instance.HttpClient.GetAsync (url);
    await HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();

    ImageBytes = await HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ();

    if (ImageBytes != null && ImageBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        imageBitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);

    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG is a compressed image format. 77KB is the compressed size. But when you decode to a Bitmap, you are decompressing it. 1638400 is the actual size of the image (width times height times color-depth).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read that BitmapFactory supported JPEG so I assumed it worked with the compressed file. Is there a way if doing that? My app is filling up with a lot of album art which only takes 77KB but amounts to 100MB using bitmap factory. Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html . In brief: make sure you're decoding to the correct size, transparency, and color depth; and call Bitmap.recycle() as soon as it's off the screen.